# R - how to use the exposition pipe %$% in purrr::map

Tags: r, pipe, purrr, magrittr

For the purposes of this question, let's split the `mtcars` dataset into several smaller ones, for example based on `carb` and store them all in a list

```
mtlist <- group_split(mtcars, carb)
```

Let's now say that, only on one of these datasets, I am operating some pipeline and in the end I want to select a single variable using the exposition operator `%$%`:

```
mtlist[[1]] %>% 
mutate(cyl = 6*cyl) %$%
cyl
```

Output:

```
24 36 36 24 24 24 24
```

However, what if I wish to do so on the whole `mtlist`? The following doesn't work:

```
mtlist %>% 
  map(mutate, cyl = 6*cyl) %$%
  cyl
```

So what would be the way to do it?

I know that I can achieve the same final output in other ways, e.g. `map(select, cyl)`, but I am looking to learn how to do it ***specifically*** with the exposition pipe `%$%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of `%$%`, it says that:

> [%$%] [e]xpose the names in lhs to the rhs expression. This is useful when functions do not have a built-in data argument.

In your case the names of the `lhs` are the names of the list, so you cannot really use `cyl` directly. You have to do it inside a `map` call:

```r
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

mtlist %>% 
  map(mutate, cyl = 6*cyl) %>%
  map(~ .x %$% cyl)
```

returning

```r
[[1]]
[1] 24 36 36 24 24 24 24

[[2]]
 [1] 48 24 24 24 48 48 48 24 24 24

[[3]]
[1] 48 48 48

[[4]]
 [1] 36 36 48 36 36 48 48 48 48 48

[[5]]
[1] 36

[[6]]
[1] 48
```

Comment: Bon travail monsieur Mael!